# Trying to click specific slot in FullCalendar using Nightwatch

Tags: fullcalendar, nightwatch.js

I have hard time clicking the slot I want in Fullcalendar using Nightwatch.

All I have is:
`await browser.click('css selector', 'td.fc-timegrid-slot.fc-timegrid-slot-lane')`

which surprisingly (in `timeGrid` view type) click on the Thursday weekday where I want Monday or any other day (ergo: I want to be able to control it).

How to do it?

Comment: If you examine the HTML for the timegrid week view you'll see there's no single HTML element which defines a single slot (e.g. 7am on Tuesday). The grid you see is actually an optical illusion caused by overlaying HTML tables on top of each other. There are no individual "cells" you can identify from the HTML structure. When you select a slot in fullCalendar, it knows what you selected because internally it knows the absolute positions of the notional "cells" on the page. But there's no external exposure of that data either through the HTML or through the JS API.

Comment: So essentially what I'm saying is your task is probably impossible, unless your library allows you to click on a set of on-screen co-ordinates, which you'd have to pre-calculate carefully, instead of on HTML elements. (N.B. In the timegrid "day" view then it's more reliable because you can identify the slot by its row, and there's only one day so you know it's always the right one. So you could probably test that with this method, and the "month" view as well, but not much else.)